# extract word content using word interop causes an error

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-interop

I am trying to extract word content using this code :

```
// Open a doc file.
            Application application = new Application();
            Document document = application.Documents.Open("d:\\a.doc");

            // Loop through all words in the document.
            int count = document.Words.Count;
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
            {
                // Write the word.
                string text = document.Words[i].Text;
                Console.WriteLine("Word {0} = {1}", i, text);
            }
            // Close word.
            application.Quit();
```

But after running i get this error:

```
    Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass' to interface type 
'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application'. This operation failed
 because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the 
interface with IID '{00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'
 failed due to the following error:
 No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

I have installed office 2013

Comment: *But after running i get this error* on which line?

Comment: @MattBurland             Document document = application.Documents.Open("d:\\a.doc");

Comment: Try `var application = new Word._Application();` and `var document = application.Documents.Open(@"D:\a.doc");`

Comment: Maybe I have it the wrong way around, try `var application = new Word.Application();`. I can't remember whether you need the underscore or not.

Comment: @Equalsk can't resolve Word.application !!!

Comment: Do you have a "using" statement at the top of the code page that refers to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word namespace: using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word? And have you also set a Reference to that library? You MUST have the Reference. The using statement is optional, but if you don't have it the way I showed then you need to fully quality every object from that namespace when you declare it. (var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally download `aspire.doc` nuget and use it to extract the content of word file  as you can see:

```
   Document document = new Document();
            document.LoadFromFile(@"d:\a.docx");

            //Initialzie StringBuilder Instance
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            //Extract Text from Word and Save to StringBuilder Instance
            foreach (Section section in document.Sections)
            {
                foreach (Paragraph paragraph in section.Paragraphs)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(paragraph.Text);
                }
            }

            //Create a New TXT File to Save Extracted Text
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
```